# What Values Do Memory Units in LSTM Memorize?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

Let's say I allocate 6 memory units and feed the lstm dataset with each sample containing 3 Time Steps and 2 features.
Does this mean my lstm will memorize maximum of 6 samples, 6 steps, or 6 features? In other words, 6 samples, 2 samples, or 1 sample?

1. 6 samples, total of 6*3*2=36 values,
2. 6 steps (6 / 3 steps = 2 samples), total of 6*2 = 12 values,
3. 6 features (6 / 3 steps / 2 features = 1 sample, total of 6 values

Comment: That depends entirely on the parameters and as such on what the LSTM learned. You cannot make blanket statements about the network "remembering" x many inputs.

Comment: Thanks @xdurch0. Is there a guideline on how many units to allocate based on the input size, or is it just trial and error?

Comment: I don't think so. Understanding both the the theoretical limitations of neural networks as well as what they will actually learn in practice is difficult and an active research field. Most papers I see use something between 256-1024 or so units (and often multiple LTSMs stacked). Your best bet would be to read some papers that deal with related problems and look at what parameters they use.